# I am confused about something in python to send an HTTP request that I am trying to recreate in java

Tags: java, python, http, http-post, httpurlconnection

My friend recently sent me this code:

```
requests.post("example.com", headers = {'authorization': token}, json = {'content' : message})
```

it is in python. It is meant to send an HTTP post request to example.com and I am trying to convert it to java.

So far, I have this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
//url is defined farther up in the code.
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
```

However, in my friends code he had 2 different parts that were `headers={}` and `json={}`

I don't know how I would do this in java. I am confused what the difference between headers and json is. How would I choose the content of the message? please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand you having issues adding the json content to the request?

setRequestProperty() in java is the same in python as doing the following:

```
headers = {}
headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
headers['Authorization'] = token
```

I haven't written in Java for a long time but from what I have read you need to do the following:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// This part sends the json data to the output stream with the headers defined above sent with the data
String inputString = "{variable1: "myvariable1", variable2; "myvariable2"}";
try(OutputStream stream = con.getOutputStream()){
    byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("utf-8");
    stream.write(input, 0, input.length);
}
```

You are already setting the headers via "setRequestProperty()" you just need to send the data as well.

Comment: I tried to do something similar, but it did not work. It did not give me any errors though.